# Powershell ScreenShot of a particular part

Tags: image, powershell, screenshot

I want to take a screenshot of a very particular part of the screen. As if I just want to take a screenshot of an image in the centre of the screen. How can I do that? How can I setthe alignment to only crop a particular area. I got the code from stackoverflow only to take a screenshot:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")
function screenshot([Drawing.Rectangle]$bounds, $path) {
   $bmp = New-Object Drawing.Bitmap $bounds.width, $bounds.height
   $graphics = [Drawing.Graphics]::FromImage($bmp)

   $graphics.CopyFromScreen($bounds.Location, [Drawing.Point]::Empty, $bounds.size)

   $bmp.Save($path)

   $graphics.Dispose()
   $bmp.Dispose()
}

$bounds = [Drawing.Rectangle]::FromLTRB(0, 0, 1000, 900)
screenshot $bounds "C:\screenshot.jpeg"
```

If we could edit this.

Comment: Why is this tagged javascript or arrays?

Answer (score 1):

For craps and laughter I made something here that will make a screenshot of a rectangle that is centered on the screen.

```
$captureSize = @{ Height = 300; Width = 200}
$screenDimensions = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_DesktopMonitor | Select-Object -First 1 ScreenWidth,ScreenHeight
$screenCenterPoint = @{FromTop = ($screenDimensions.ScreenHeight) / 2; FromLeft = ($screenDimensions.ScreenWidth) /2 }
$box = @{}
$box.Left = $screenCenterPoint.FromLeft - $captureSize.Width / 2
$box.Top = $screenCenterPoint.FromTop - $captureSize.Height / 2
$box.Right = $box.Left + $captureSize.Width
$box.Bottom = $box.Top + $captureSize.Height

$bounds = [Drawing.Rectangle]::FromLTRB($box.Left,$box.Top,$box.Right,$box.Bottom)
```

Set `$captureSize`  to the values that you want. Using the SO question that was linked by Alpha M Cubed [Get Screen resolution using WMI/powershell in Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967699/get-screen-resolution-using-wmi-powershell-in-windows-7) we populate the "primary screen" dimensions into `$screenDimensions`. Using some simple math *with no error detection what so ever* we figure the location of the box relative to the center of the screen. The function and function call stay the same.

Answer (score -1):

The code already includes the solution, it takes a rectangle, $bounds. Move that to your preferred position. If you'd like to find the size of the monitor you can refer to this question: [Get Screen resolution using WMI/powershell in Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967699/get-screen-resolution-using-wmi-powershell-in-windows-7)
I will also mention that the current code (I think) saves in BMP format, while you specified a .jpeg extension.