# How to use path as parameter?

Tags: powershell, parameters

I would like to have a screenshot tool in PS. Because I don't want to reinvent the wheel I searched and found a script at github (https://github.com/mikepruett3/psfetch), which I adapted for my needs.

Now I would like to change the behaviour - when the script is started with no parameter it should make a screenshot in the current directory. If the user enters a path (with `-Path`) the screenshot should be saved there.

My idea was to define (in my case) `$Tarpath` and redefine it when the option is given. How to do this?

Here is my actual script:

```
# PSFetch.ps1
# A Screenfetch writen in PowerShell
#
# -----------------------------------------------------------
# The Original Inspirations for CMDfetch:
# -----------------------------------------------------------
# screenFetch by KittyKatt
#   https://github.com/KittyKatt/screenFetch
#   A very nice screenshotting and information tool. For GNU/Linux (Almost all Major Distros Supported) *This has been ported to Windows, link below.*
#
# archey by djmelik
#   https://github.com/djmelik/archey
#   Another nice screenshotting and information tool. More hardware oriented than screenFetch. For GNU/Linux
# -----------------------------------------------------------
#

# DONE: Function to Take the Screenshot
Function Take-Screenshot {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [string]$Width,
        [string]$Height,
        [string]$TarPath = "$PSScriptRoot"
    )

    PROCESS {
        [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") > $Null

        # Changed how $bounds is calculated so that screen shots with multiple monitors that are offset work correctly
        $bounds = [Windows.Forms.SystemInformation]::VirtualScreen
        # Check Path for Trailing BackSlashes
#           $TarPath = $PSScriptRoot
        if ( $TarPath.EndsWith("\") ) {
            $TarPath = $TarPath.Substring(0,$Path.Length-1)
        }

        # Define The Target Path
        $stamp = get-date -f MM-dd-yyyy_HH_mm_ss
        $target = "$TarPath\screenshot-$stamp.png"

        # Take the Screenshot
        $bmp = New-Object Drawing.Bitmap $bounds.width, $bounds.height
        $graphics = [Drawing.Graphics]::FromImage($bmp)
        $graphics.CopyFromScreen($bounds.Location, [Drawing.Point]::Empty, $bounds.size)
        $bmp.Save($target)
        $graphics.Dispose()
        $bmp.Dispose()
    }
}

# DONE: Fix support for Multiple Monitors
# FROM: Shay Levy's Response -     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967699/get-screen-resolution-using-wmi-powershell-in-windows-7
$ScreenWidth = 0
$ScreenHeight = 0
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$DisplayCount = [System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::AllScreens.Bounds.Count
$Bounds = [System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::AllScreens | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Bounds

$ScreenWidth = $Bounds | Measure-Object -Property Width -Sum | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Sum
$ScreenHeight = $Bounds | Measure-Object -Property Height -Maximum | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Maximum

$RESOLUTION = "$ScreenWidth x $ScreenHeight"

# Take Screenshot if the Parameters are assigned...
Take-Screenshot -Width $ScreenWidth -Height $ScreenHeight -TarPath $target
```

*edit*
i forgot to remove the $tarpath int the PROCESS-block.
It remained here from my first tests...

Comment: But reinventing the wheel is fun :p

Answer (score 2):

OK, I solved it myself.

First of all `[string]$TarPath = "$PSScriptRoot"` doesn't work at all!
The variable is always empty.

However, my first idea was to define `$TarPath` and leave it unchanged until it defined again. This turned out that doesn't work.

Here is my solution:

```
# Define The Target Path
Write-Host "Please enter Screenshot-Path"
$TarPath = Read-Host "Else the screenshot will be in $PWD"
if (!$TarPath) {$TarPath = $pwd}
```

If nothing is entered at the prompt `$pwd` will be used.

Comment: Apparently you're using PowerShell v2.0. You should've mentioned that.

Comment: No, Sir - i´m using the actual PS-Version...

     $PSVersionTable
      PSVersion                      5.0.10105.0

Comment: Can't reproduce. `$PSScriptRoot` works just fine in PowerShell v5 (5.0.10514.6) on Windows 10 or Server 2012 R2.

Comment: $PSScriptRoot doesn't exist during parameter initialization; it gets defined afterwards. I've worked around this by doing something like `if (-not $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Path') { $Path = $PSScriptRoot }` after the starting `param` block, similar to Ansgar's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You redifine `$TarPath` in your function body:

```
$TarPath = $PSScriptRoot
```

This unconditionally supersedes any value previously assigned to the parameter. Remove the line and you can pass the parameter like this:

```
Take-Screenshot -TarPath 'C:\some\folder'
```

or omit the parameter to leave it at its default value (`$PSScriptRoot`).

I'd recommend to also change the line

```
$target = "$TarPath\screenshot-$stamp.png"
```

into this:

```
$target = Join-Path $TarPath "screenshot-$stamp.png"
```

so you don't need to fiddle around with trailing backslashes.

```
Function Take-Screenshot {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [string]$Width,
        [string]$Height,
        [string]$TarPath = "$PSScriptRoot"
    )

    PROCESS {
        [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") > $Null

        # Changed how $bounds is calculated so that screen shots with multiple monitors that are offset work correctly
        $bounds = [Windows.Forms.SystemInformation]::VirtualScreen

        # Define The Target Path
        $stamp = get-date -f MM-dd-yyyy_HH_mm_ss
        $target = Join-Path $TarPath "screenshot-$stamp.png"

        # Take the Screenshot
        $bmp = New-Object Drawing.Bitmap $bounds.width, $bounds.height
        $graphics = [Drawing.Graphics]::FromImage($bmp)
        $graphics.CopyFromScreen($bounds.Location, [Drawing.Point]::Empty, $bounds.size)
        $bmp.Save($target)
        $graphics.Dispose()
        $bmp.Dispose()
    }
}
```

---

**Addendum:** There are two scenarios where defining the default value for the parameter `-TarPath` as `$TarPath = "$PSScriptRoot"` doesn't work:

- The parameter is defined as a parameter to the script (not to a function within the script) and the script is run from CMD:

  ```
  powershell -File 'C:\path\to\script.ps1'
  ```
- The script is run with PowerShell v2. The variable was only available in modules prior to PowerShell v3.

In both scenarios `"$PScriptRoot"` can be replaced with `$PWD.Path`:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [string]$Width,
    [string]$Height,
    [string]$TarPath = $PWD.Path
)
```

Comment: I wonder if there's a better type than `[string]` for `$TarPath`? Is there no object that represents a path in .NET?

Comment: @KolobCanyon You could use `[System.IO.FileInfo]`, but what would be the advantage?

Comment: Idk, maybe there's some built in validation or something useful in that class? I find myself having to write `if(-not (Test-Path $path)) { Write-Error "invalid path: $path" }` a lot

Comment: You could use parameter validation for that. Besides, just because a path doesn't exist (yet) doesn't automatically mean it's invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes, that's about it, that approach will work. The only thing is that in the `PROCESS` block, you re-assign once again your `$TarPath`, making your fallback mechanism ineffective:

```
$TarPath = $PSScriptRoot
```

Delete that line and it will work like a charm.

Additionally, you could add validations such as making sure the parameter can be null, but not empty, and must be a valid path:

```
[ValidateScript({if ($_){  Test-Path $_}})]
[string]$TarPath = "$PSScriptRoot"
```

One last thing, if you want, as described in your question, to let the user use `-Path` on the call, you can also add an alias to your `Param`.

```
[Alias('Path')]
[ValidateScript({if ($_){  Test-Path $_}})]
[string]$Path = "$PSScriptRoot"
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to modify the last line of the script with either of the following:

For default directory:

```
Take-Screenshot -Width $ScreenWidth -Height $ScreenHeight
```

For custom directory:

```
Take-Screenshot -Width $ScreenWidth -Height $ScreenHeight -TarPath "D:\Piyush\temp"
```

And comment out the following line in the PROCESS block as you don't want to override the custom directory path with the default one.

```
$TarPath = $PSScriptRoot
```

Comment: If i change it this was the script creates two screenshots...
I tried ./psfetch -tarpath "D:\aaa" and it makes one in the actual dir and the second in D:\ (and not in the subdir)

Comment: First, you're supposed to call any one of the `Take-Screenshot` with any one of the given approach. Either with 3 args or 2 args as per your need. In that way there will only be 1 screenshot generated. Next, for `D:\aaa` can you confirm if the folder, aaa, already exist or not?