# PowerShell script returning the wrong screen resolution

Tags: winforms, powershell, winapi, screen-resolution

I just wrote a simple PowerShell script to get the screen resolution of my monitor, but it seems to be returning the wrong values.

```
# Returns an screen width and screen height of maximum screen resolution
function Get-ScreenSize {
    $screen = [System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::PrimaryScreen
    $width  = $screen.Bounds.Width
    $height = $screen.Bounds.Height
    return $width, $height
}

Get-ScreenSize
```

I am running this script on a 4k monitor with the resolution set at 3840 x 2160, but it is giving me the following output:

> 1536
>
> 864

Is there anything that would cause `System.Windows.Forms.Screen` to get the wrong "Bounds" values?

Comment: What values do you get when using the [WorkingArea](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.workingarea.aspx) instead of the [Bounds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.bounds.aspx) property?

Comment: I get 3840 x 2060 which is very close, but still not quite correct.

Comment: That looks correct. Full width, and height minus the taskbar.

Comment: Okay, hmm then I wonder why bounds is returning the wrong value...

Comment: Looking at the reference implementation for [Screen](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Screen.cs,61c7e4f4309b6603), it looks like `Bounds` uses the virtual screen size (not entirely sure, why the numbers are smaller than expected, though), while `WorkingArea` uses the multi-monitor API. I don't know how to fix the PowerShell commandlet, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because that command gives you the scaled resolution. If you're running 3840 x 2160 but you're not running on 100% scaling you'll get a different value.

Comment: That is very interesting, but I guess it makes sense if that's the command apps use internally to scale themselves properly.

Answer (score 5):

Well I didn't exactly find out why I was getting such strange results... but I did find another approach that actually seems simpler and appears to be accurate.

```
$vc = Get-WmiObject -class "Win32_VideoController"
$vc.CurrentHorizontalResolution
$vc.CurrentVerticalResolution
```

This will print the current screen resolution and appears to be giving me accurate results which is what I was actually looking for.  If anyone figures out what could cause the other approach to produce inaccurate results I would still really like to know why it is happening though...

Answer (score -2):

That's odd.

Why on earth has Microsoft only provided the [Get-DisplayResolution](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj603037(v=wps.630).aspx) cmdlet with Server Core?

That edition ships without a Start-button... and according to the comment above on the returned display size (minus start-bar); I won't be surprised to hear that cmdlet is using the same .NET code library.

Quick search in my HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control lists a few keys for monitors and values per screen, but nothing useful.

---

Edit: see [Q7967699](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7968063/6055487).

```
PS D:\Scripts> Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

PS D:\Scripts> [System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::AllScreens


BitsPerPixel : 32
Bounds       : {X=0,Y=0,Width=3840,Height=2160}
DeviceName   : \\.\DISPLAY1
Primary      : True
WorkingArea  : {X=0,Y=0,Width=3840,Height=2120}
```