# Multiple monitors/graphic cards info using powershell

Tags: powershell, wmi

I am using the following script to get system information. The script works fine, I have problem when computers with two graphic cards or multiple monitors.
For more monitors I found this [Get Screen resolution using WMI/powershell in Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967699/get-screen-resolution-using-wmi-powershell-in-windows-7) 
but don't know how to format/implement it to fit my script.

```
$user = [Environment]::UserName
$System = Get-CimInstance CIM_ComputerSystem
$BIOS = Get-CimInstance CIM_BIOSElement
$OS = Get-CimInstance CIM_OperatingSystem
$CPU = Get-CimInstance CIM_Processor
$osup = Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem
$uptime = (Get-Date) - ($osup.ConvertToDateTime($osup.lastbootuptime))
$GPU = Get-CimInstance CIM_VideoController
$RES = Get-WmiObject Win32_VideoController
$used = ($System.TotalPhysicalMemory/1MB)-($OS.FreePhysicalMemory/1KB)

$EXTXT = "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\vq.txt"

Clear-Host

$user + "@" + $system.Name >> $EXTXT
"OS: " + $OS.caption + " " + $osup.OSArchitecture >> $EXTXT
"Model: " + $System.Model >> $EXTXT
"Kernel: " + $OS.Version >> $EXTXT
"Uptime: " + $Uptime.Days + "d " + $Uptime.Hours + "h " + $Uptime.Minutes + "m " >> $EXTXT
"Resolution: " + $RES.CurrentHorizontalResolution + "x" + $RES.CurrentVerticalResolution >> $EXTXT
"CPU: " + $CPU.Name >> $EXTXT
"GPU: " + $GPU.Name >> $EXTXT
"Memory: " + "{0:N0}" -f $used + "MB" + " / " + "{0:N0}" -f ($System.TotalPhysicalMemory/1MB) + "MB" >> $EXTXT
```

I basically want to get file with information in lines, with GPU separated with comma and detection for multiple screens and if there are multiple monitors printed their respective resolutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest changing the line `$GPU =` to

```
$GPU=(Get-CimInstance CIM_VideoController|%{$_.Name}) -join("; ")
[void] [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms.Screens") 
$Screens = ([system.windows.forms.screen]::AllScreens | %{"$($_.Bounds.width)x$($_.Bounds.Height)"}) -join("; ")
```

and `"GPU: " + $GPU.Name >> $EXTXT` to

```
"GPU: " + $GPU >> $EXTXT
"Resolution: " + $Screens
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. What about resolution of said monitors?
"Resolution: " + $RES.CurrentHorizontalResolution + "x" + $RES.CurrentVerticalResolution >> $EXTXT
will get something like: Resolution: 1920 1920 x 1080 1080

Comment: @JakubZahorak Changed the above script.

Comment: On laptop (2xGPU, 2xmonitor):
Monitor: Default Monitor 1366x768; Dell P2414H(Analog) 1920x1080
On desktop (1xGPU, 1xmonitor)
Monitor: SyncMaster XL2370(Digital) x
    `-Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_DesktopMonitor` will also result in empty Width and Height :/
    `-Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_VideoController` will fetch Width and Height, (with one monitor) but only resolution of main monitor on laptop

Comment: I do get also inconsistent results on the dual monitor pcs I tested. [this link](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/707515-monitor-inventory) provides some monitor info not presented by the above cmdlets/methods, but not the resolution :-\

Comment: `[void] [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms.Screens")
$Screens = ([system.windows.forms.screen]::AllScreens | ForEach-Object {"$($_.Bounds.width)x$($_.Bounds.Height)"}) -join("; ")`
and `"Resolution: " + $Screens >> $EXTXT`
Did the trick in the end. Thanks @LotPings for help

Comment: @JakubZahorak Ty, I inserted your code to present a complete answer.