# windows-how to get screen resolution in golang

Tags: windows, go, size, screen

Great guy.

I have a requirement to get the windows system screen resolution,but I can't get any useful thing about this with google.

So I look for help in stackoverflow.

Anyone know how to do it?

Thanks advance.

updates:
then I try this command`wmic desktopmonitor get screenheight screenwidth` and get the answer like this:
this is the cmd:
[image]

this is go-program:
[image]

Answer (score 7):

A bit late, but as suggested by Marco, you can use the Windows API [GetSystemMetrics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724385(v=vs.85).aspx) for this. The easiest way to do so is through the [github.com/lxn/win](https://github.com/lxn/win) package:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/lxn/win"
)

func main() {
    width := int(win.GetSystemMetrics(win.SM_CXSCREEN))
    height := int(win.GetSystemMetrics(win.SM_CYSCREEN))
    fmt.Printf("%dx%d\n", width, height)
}
```

Slightly more elaborate, using [GetDeviceCaps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144877(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/lxn/win"
)

func main() {
    hDC := win.GetDC(0)
    defer win.ReleaseDC(0, hDC)
    width := int(win.GetDeviceCaps(hDC, win.HORZRES))
    height := int(win.GetDeviceCaps(hDC, win.VERTRES))
    fmt.Printf("%dx%d\n", width, height)
}
```

Comment: This works great for single-monitor setups.  I'm trying to work out how to get all raster display devices enumerated and get their positions relative to each other.  If anyone knows a way to do this, please enlighten me.

Comment: If it helps anyone, Microsoft have a guide for now to do this in C++ here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/positioning-objects-on-a-multiple-display-setup

Answer (score 2):

We can get screen resolution through `powershell`, and its are arguments are its scripts.
so, I have included script in `args` variable.

Output is not straight forward, you will get someother extra information, try using `bytes` package or `strings` package to scan required information.

Following `powershell` command is retrived from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967699/get-screen-resolution-using-wmi-powershell-in-windows-7):

`Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms;[System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::AllScreens`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    args := "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms;[System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::AllScreens"
    out, err := exec.Command("powershell", args).Output()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    fmt.Print(string(out))
}
```

I have checked it in Windows 7 Virtual box, its working.
You can run this from `Command Prompt` or `powershell`, as this calls `powershell` any how.

Answer (score 2):

I was encountering the same problem and doing it via exec.Command is not an option for me.

The windows api has a function which allows you to obtain the screen resolution, so you only need to load the proper dll and call the function.

```
package main 

import (
    "fmt"
    "syscall"
)

var (
    user32           = syscall.NewLazyDLL("User32.dll")
    getSystemMetrics = user32.NewProc("GetSystemMetrics")
)

func GetSystemMetrics(nIndex int) int {
    index := uintptr(nIndex)
    ret, _, _ := getSystemMetrics.Call(index)
    return int(ret)
}

const (
    SM_CXSCREEN = 0
    SM_CYSCREEN = 1
)

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("X: %d, Y: %d\n", GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN),GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN))
}
```

Official Documentation:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724385(v=vs.85).aspx

https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/WindowsDLLs

https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#Syscall

Answer (score 1):

I did some digging for you and found a way to get your screens width and height via command line in windows:

```
wmic desktopmonitor get screenheight, screenwidth
```

So all you have to do is execute this command in a Go program and print the output!

```
package main

import (
  "os/exec"
  "fmt"
  "log"
  "os"
)

func main() {
  command:= "wmic"
  args := []string{"desktopmonitor", "get", "screenheight,", "screenwidth"}
  cmd := exec.Command(command, args...)
  cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
  out, err := cmd.Output()
  fmt.Printf("out: %#v\n", string(out))
  fmt.Printf("err: %#v\n", err)
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }
}
```

Here is the Go Playground link : https://play.golang.org/p/KdIhrd3H1x

Comment: wonderful~! this is a good way~! I try this command,there return nothing

Comment: What does it return? Simply nothing?

Comment: Are you using a laptop or a monitor?

Comment: It's a monitor.