# Why do I get empty for screen resolution in PowerShell on Windows 10?

Tags: powershell, wmi

I type the command in [Get Screen resolution using WMI/powershell in Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967699/get-screen-resolution-using-wmi-powershell-in-windows-7), but I get empty result (I'm on Surface Pro 2017, single screen)?

[image]

Comment: What do you get for this? `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Desktopmonitor`

Comment: @RohinSidharth empty also
DeviceID            : DesktopMonitor1
DisplayType         :
MonitorManufacturer : Surface
Name                : Surface Display
ScreenHeight        :
ScreenWidth         :

Comment: @ansgarwiechers why is my question voted to close just because nobody knows the answer about wmi ? I know there is alternative with winform but that's not my question, my question is about wmi.

Comment: @user310291 You need to ask that the person who close-voted this question.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers is there a way to know who downvoted though ?

Comment: No. This behavior is by design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have a Surface, but does this work?

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$screen = [System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::PrimaryScreen
[pscustomobject]@{
    DeviceName   = $screen.DeviceName.Split('\\')[-1]
    Width        = $screen.Bounds.Width
    Height       = $screen.Bounds.Height
    BitsPerPixel = $screen.BitsPerPixel
}
```

**EDIT**

Using CIM_VideoController

```
$screen = Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_VideoController
[pscustomobject]@{
    DeviceName   = $screen.Caption
    Width        = $screen.CurrentHorizontalResolution
    Height       = $screen.CurrentVerticalResolution
    BitsPerPixel = $screen.CurrentBitsPerPixel
}
```

Comment: yes it works and I know it works but my question is about wmi ;)

Comment: Apparently, starting with Windows Vista, hardware that is not compatible with Longhorn Display Driver Model (LDDM) returns inaccurate property values for instances of this class. Instead, you can use the `CIM_VideoController` object and get properties `CurrentHorizontalResolution`, `CurrentVerticalResolution` and `CurrentBitsPerPixel` from that (and more). Usage `Get-CimInstance -ClassName  CIM_VideoController`

Comment: I'm on a Surface Pro 3 (Windows 10 Build 17713) and `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Desktopmonitor` correctly returns `ScreenWidth  : 2160 ScreenHeight : 1440`

Comment: @Jacob well that's ironic that old version of surface works ;)

Comment: @Theo  CIM_VideoController returns something : 2736   1824 which are maximum resolution I guess whereas my current resolution is set lower. But since that's also an interesting info, I'll check as good answer :)