# WMI return resolution of laptop display that is not active

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to get resolution information of a laptops built in display that is not in use? (i.e. laptop is docked using external monitors only)
I have tried using Get-WmiObject etc but it only returns active displays.  Does WMI only have info on monitors that are currently connected and turned on?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Screen resolution using WMI/powershell in Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967699/get-screen-resolution-using-wmi-powershell-in-windows-7)

Comment: The suggested duplicate solution only returns active displays.

Comment: Then what do you mean by built in display that is not in use ? Please edit your question by adding the output of `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_DesktopMonitor`.

Comment: I have edited my question as much as I can to try to make sense.  The laptop is closed and plugged in to a dock so it is only using external monitors, the built in one is not on.  I want to know if it is possible to extract any information about the resolutions that the built in monitor is capable of.  I suspect the answer may be no.

Comment: Well you answered your question, if the monitor is off then the OS won't see it neither will Powershell.