# How to capture windows 10/windows 11 advanced display settings for multiple monitors

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to capture the following displays information connected to my laptop programatically using powershell but I am unable to find a way. This information can be found via the windows GUI at Settings > Display > Advanced Display Information (2 screenshots attached below).

Here's the information I am trying to capture

```
Display Name: (In this case, display name for internal would be but the external one would be "ASUS VP 228)

Display Resolution: 1680x1050 and 1920x1080 for the 2 displays

Whether it's an internal/external display: True and False

Refresh rate: 60Hz and 60Hz
```

Here's what I've tried

```
Get-WmiObject win32_videocontroller
```

Returns the resolution under parameter `VideoModeDescription` but even then, it seems to return the value of "Active Signal Resolution" (from the screenshot) below).

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Desktopmonitor

DeviceID            : DesktopMonitor1
DisplayType         :
MonitorManufacturer : (Standard monitor types)
Name                : Generic PnP Monitor
ScreenHeight        :
ScreenWidth         :
```

Only get output information for 1 out of the 2 monitors and don't get `ScreenHeight` or ScreenWidth` values.

```
get-ciminstance -namespace root\wmi -classname wmimonitorbasicdisplayparams


Active                        : True
DisplayTransferCharacteristic : 120
InstanceName                  : DISPLAY\IVO8C66\5&462698&0&UID256_0
MaxHorizontalImageSize        : 31
MaxVerticalImageSize          : 17
SupportedDisplayFeatures      : WmiMonitorSupportedDisplayFeatures
VideoInputType                : 1
PSComputerName                :

Active                        : True
DisplayTransferCharacteristic : 120
InstanceName                  : DISPLAY\ACI22C3\5&462698&0&UID265_0
MaxHorizontalImageSize        : 48
MaxVerticalImageSize          : 27
SupportedDisplayFeatures      : WmiMonitorSupportedDisplayFeatures
VideoInputType                : 1
PSComputerName
```

Gives me the correct monitor count but doesn't give me any other information.

I then tried using the DumpEDID tool and it gave me more information but didn't give me current monitor resolution or whether it's an internal display or not.

```
DumpEDID v1.07
Copyright (c) 2006 - 2018 Nir Sofer
Web site: http://www.nirsoft.net

*****************************************************************
Active                   : Yes
Registry Key             : DISPLAY\ACI22C3\5&462698&0&UID265
Monitor Name             : ASUS VP228
Serial Number            : G6LMTF155938
Manufacture Week         : 26 / 2016
ManufacturerID           : 26884 (0x6904)
ProductID                : 8899 (0x22C3)
Serial Number (Numeric)  : 155938 (0x00026122)
EDID Version             : 1.3
Display Gamma            : 2.20
Vertical Frequency       : 50 - 75 Hz
Horizontal Frequency     : 24 - 83 KHz
Maximum Image Size       : 48 X 27 cm (21.7 Inch)
Maximum Resolution       : 1920 X 1080
Support Standby Mode     : No
Support Suspend Mode     : No
Support Low-Power Mode   : Yes
Support Default GTF      : No
Digital                  : Yes

Supported Display Modes  :
     720 X  400  70 Hz
     640 X  480  60 Hz
     640 X  480  67 Hz
     640 X  480  72 Hz
     640 X  480  75 Hz
     800 X  600  56 Hz
     800 X  600  60 Hz
     800 X  600  72 Hz
     800 X  600  75 Hz
     832 X  624  75 Hz
    1024 X  768  60 Hz
    1024 X  768  70 Hz
    1024 X  768  75 Hz
    1280 X  720  60 Hz
    1152 X  864  75 Hz
    1280 X  960  60 Hz
    1440 X  900  60 Hz
    1280 X 1024  60 Hz
    1280 X 1024  75 Hz
    1680 X 1050  60 Hz
    1920 X 1080  60 Hz

*****************************************************************

*****************************************************************
Active                   : Yes
Registry Key             : DISPLAY\IVO8C66\5&462698&0&UID256
Manufacture Week         : 0 / 2019
ManufacturerID           : 53030 (0xCF26)
ProductID                : 35942 (0x8C66)
Serial Number (Numeric)  : 0 (0x00000000)
EDID Version             : 1.4
Display Gamma            : 2.20
Maximum Image Size       : 31 X 17 cm (13.9 Inch)
Maximum Resolution       : 1920 X 1080
Support Standby Mode     : No
Support Suspend Mode     : No
Support Low-Power Mode   : No
Support Default GTF      : No
Digital                  : Yes

Supported Display Modes  :
    1920 X 1080  60 Hz
```

The script [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63206218) gives me almost what I want except it doesn't give me the monitor name nor does it give me information whether it's internal or not.

I have attached 2 screenshots from the Settings > Display > Advanced Display page which is the information I am looking to capture.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution? I could not find one